# OpenVPN client connected, but cannot ping inside VPN address range

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I set up OpenVPN 2.1.3 on Windows 7 following the [OpenVPN Easy Windows Guide](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide#FirewallConfiguration). The client (another computer) can connect without problems and gets the desired IP x.x.x.6/255.255.255.252 in the VPN IP range. The server itself is x.x.x.1/255.255.255.252.

In my scenario, I only have clients which need to connect securely to that one server (which also runs the OpenVPN server).

**But the client and server cannot ping each other (on their VPN IP addresses).** What's wrong here?

On the server, I set "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter=1" to enable IP forwarding (and restarted of course).

(**EDIT:** I must add that ping works when I use TAP device, but how about TUN?)

Server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 192.169.0.0 255.255.255.0 # OpenVPN seems to change this to x.x.x.252
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client # not sure if I need this, just tried
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
```

Client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.1.197 1194 # That's the server's physical address on my wifi
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

**EDIT 2**

Here are the routes created by both modes:

---

`route print` on client with TUN

```
192.169.0.0     255.255.255.0      192.169.0.9     192.169.0.10     30
192.169.0.8   255.255.255.252         On-link      192.169.0.10    286
192.169.0.10  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.169.0.10    286
192.169.0.11  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.169.0.10    286
```

`route print` on server with TUN

```
192.169.0.0     255.255.255.0      192.169.0.2     192.169.0.1     30
192.169.0.0   255.255.255.252         On-link      192.169.0.1    286
192.169.0.1   255.255.255.255         On-link      192.169.0.1    286
192.169.0.3   255.255.255.255         On-link      192.169.0.1    286
```

---

`route print` on client with working TAP

```
192.169.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.169.0.8    286
192.169.0.8  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.169.0.8    286
```

`route print` on server with working TAP

```
192.169.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.169.0.1    286
192.169.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.169.0.1    286
```

Comment: When you say they can't ping each other, what interface are you pinging on the host? Public interface, tun gateway address, etc.? I have a feeling the Windows firewall is probably blocking this.

Comment: @gman: I'm pinging the addresses assigned by the VPN (defaults to 10.8.0.1 for the server, for example).

Answer (score 7):

Try running `openvpn-gui` with Administrator privileges. Without them it couldn't write proper routes. Also try playing with --ip-win32 config option. And please show output of `route print` in cases of working TAP connection and non-working TUN connection.

Comment: I added the routes to my question.

Comment: In my issue help your post "Administrator privileges" - I gave it on "c:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\*.exe", "c:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\bin\*.exe".

Answer (score 2):

Your server config file says `server 192.169.0.0 255.255.255.0`, which means your server will be assigned 192.169.0.1.

I do this for server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

client-config-dir ccd
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0

client-to-client
comp-lzo
```

And this for the clients:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote YOURHOST 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
comp-lzo

;routing tweak for winblowz client
;route-method exe
;route-delay 10
;ping-restart 60

;logging settings
mute-replay-warnings
mute 10
verb 4
log-append /var/log/vpnclient.log

;certificates / keypairs
ca ca.crt
cert cert.crt
key key.key
```

I have `push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"` because my severs LAN is that subnet.

Good luck!